# Fibonacci closure in go

Tags: go, closures, fibonacci

I am following the go tour on their official website and I have been asked to write a Fibonacci generator. Here it is:

```
 package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    first := 0
    second := 0
    return func() int{
        if(first == 0) {
         first = 1
         second = 1
         return 0
        }else {
            current := first   
            firstc := second
            second = first + second
            first = firstc
            return current
        }



    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

It works. However I consider it very ugly and I'm sure there has to be a better solution. I have been thinking about posting this on the code-review however since I'm asking for a better approach I thought this is the right place to post it.

Is there a better way to write this code?

Here is the task:

> Implement a fibonacci function that returns a function (a closure) that returns successive fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

My favorite clean way to implement iterating through the Fibonacci numbers is to use `first` as f<sub>i - 1</sub>, and `second` as f<sub>i</sub>. The Fibonacci equation states that:

f<sub>i + 1</sub> = f<sub>i</sub> + f<sub>i - 1</sub>

Except when we write this in code, in the next round we're incrementing `i`. So we're effectively doing:

f<sub>next i</sub> = f<sub>current i</sub> + f<sub>current i - 1</sub>

and

f<sub>next i - 1</sub> = f<sub>current i</sub>

The way I like to implement this in code is:

```
first, second = second, first + second
```

The `first = second` part corresponds to updating f<sub>next i - 1</sub>  = f<sub>current i</sub>, and the `second = first + second` part corresponds to updating f<sub>next i</sub> = f<sub>current i</sub> + f<sub>current i - 1</sub>.

Then all we have left to do is return the old value of first, so we'll store it in a temp variable out of the way before doing the update. In total, we get:

```
// fibonacci returns a function that returns
// successive fibonacci numbers from each
// successive call
func fibonacci() func() int {
    first, second := 0, 1
    return func() int {
        ret := first
        first, second = second, first+second
        return ret
    }
}
```

See it in action on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/tR1q5MM-Pf).

Answer (score 9):

A small trick

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    a := 0
    b := 1
    return func() int {
        a, b = b, a+b
        return b-a
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Another approach

```
func fibonacci() func() int {
    n1, n := -1, 1
    return func() int {
        n1, n = n, n1+n
        return n
    }
}
```

[The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/z-X5ZTmPEJ2)

Answer (score 5):

I would make use of multiple assignment, reduce the length of identifiers, and remove that if statment:

```
func fibonacci() func() int {
    var a, b int
    b = 1
    return func() int {
        ret := a
        a, b = b, a+b
        return ret
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I have done.

```
func fibonacci() func() int {
     var s = []int{0,1}

     return func() int{
                ret := s[0]
                s[0],s[1] = s[1],s[0]+s[1]
                return ret
            }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Besides the already provided answers you could also use a defer function for it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    secondLast := 0
    last := 1
    return func() int {
        defer func() {
            secondLast, last = last, secondLast+last
        }()
        return secondLast
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NxJBP8fYk1d)

But i guess jwoodalls answers is the most performant one.

Edit: But if you wanna use unsigned integers (to show off how many fibonacci numbers you can compute on your architecture ;) ) you would have to use either the approach with the variable holding the return value or the defer function.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an uint.
func fibonacci() func() uint {
    var secondLast uint
    var last uint = 1
    return func() uint {
        defer func() {
            secondLast, last = last, secondLast + last
        }()
        return secondLast
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HCA8raT7B3D)

EditEdit: Or even better: use float64!!!

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an float64.
func fibonacci() func() float64 {
    var secondLast float64
    var last float64 = 1
    return func() float64 {
        defer func() {
            secondLast, last = last, secondLast+last
        }()
        return secondLast
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/HKDAaE_7m4L)

Answer (score 3):

Here is also my suggestion by storing each number in a Map.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
// 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610,
// 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025,
// 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229
func fibonacci() func() int {
    numbers := make(map[int]int)
    n := 0
    return func() int {
        if n == 0 {
            numbers[n] = 0
            n++
            return 0
        }
        if n == 1 {
            numbers[n] = 1
            n++
            return 1
        }
        number := numbers[n-1] + numbers[n-2]
        numbers[n] = number
        n++
        return number
    }}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or u may use this approach...simple and understandable, though not very different from the previous answers.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    f1 := 0
    f2 := 1
    return func() int {
        temp := f1+f2
        temp2 := f1
        f1 = f2
        f2 = temp
        return temp2
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    a, b, sum := 1, 1, 0
    return func() int {
        a,b = b,sum
        sum = a + b
        return b
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of trouble with this exercise as well, thank you to everyone for these answers. Thought I would also share that if you continue the go tour and make it to the concurrency section, there is another way to implement this using channels in [concurrency lesson 4](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/4).

Code snippet from lesson 4:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func fibonacci(n int, c chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        c <- x
        x, y = y, x+y
    }
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 10)
    go fibonacci(cap(c), c)
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution if you want that your answer start with zero.

```
func fibonacci() func() int {
    a, b := 0, 1
    upd := func() { a, b = b, a+b }
    return func() int {
        defer upd()
        return a
    }
}

func main() {
    fib := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(fib())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    r := []int{0,0,1}
    return func() int{
        r = []int{r[1],r[2],r[1]+r[2]}
        return r[0]
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement a recursive closure solution using hints from this post on the correct recursive syntax in go:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34194763/1592607

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func(int) int {
  var recur func(int) int
  recur = func(x int) int {
    switch x {
      case 0:
        return 0
      case 1:
        return 1
      default:
        return (recur(x - 1) + recur(x - 2))
    }
  }
  return recur
}

func main() {
  f := fibonacci()
  for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    fmt.Println(f(i))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func fibonacci() func() int {
    left, right := 0, 1
    return func() int {
        left, right = right, left+right
        return right-left
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Comment: Looks a lot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51997446/) answer. It even seems to do the same thing. Does this offer some significant advantage?

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import "fmt"

// fibonacci is a function that returns
// a function that returns an int.
func fibonacci() func() int {
    first:=0
    second:=0
    return func() int{
        if second == 0 {
            second = 1
        } else if first == 0 {
            first = 1
        } else {
            first, second = second, first + second
        }
        return second
    }
}

func main() {
    f := fibonacci()
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println(f())
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

var (
    a     int = 1
    b     int = 2
    start time.Time
)

func main() {
    // fmt.Printf("New %v %v \n", a, b)
    if start.IsZero() == true {
        start = time.Now()
    }

    defer recoverMain()
    fmt.Println(a)
    if b > 1000000 {
        sub := time.Since(start)
        fmt.Printf("work time  %v \n", sub.Microseconds())
        return
    }
    a, b = b, a+b
    panic("start")
}

func recoverMain() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        main()
    }
    // return
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).