# How to recurse a closure in Go?

Tags: recursion, go, closures

How to recurse a closure in Go?

Suppose I have a closure like

```
recur := func(){
    recur()
}
```

Compiler says:

> undefined: recur

How can i implement it? Why is it happening?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

it happens because of [how the order of evaluation works](https://tip.golang.org/ref/spec#Order_of_evaluation).

As of December 2015 (go.1.5.1), there isn't any language feature providing it.

Possible workarounds:

```
var recur func()
recur = func(){
    recur()
}

//or

type recurF func(recurF)

recur := func(recur recurF) {
    recur(recur)
}
```

More Info: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/226